# Multi-Page Order Form with sessions

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

For my web dev class we have to create a login page, verify it against encrypted records (Id, password) that we have to enter, then step through an order form (while being able to step forward and backward throughout).. so sessions and all that.. I have no idea where to even start aside from coding the html which I've already done.. Any pushes in the right direction would be helpful.. my instructor is abrasive and refuses to help most people without degrading them first.

Comment: Here is an intuitive tutorial on sessions => http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html - *Plus*, don't encrypt (passwords), "hash".

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda like a longer question.

First at login form you need to check with MYSQL / SQL / DB / etc if the username and password matches.

It's basically like this:

```
 SELECT * from users WHERE username = 'username' AND pass = 'sha1(password)'
```

Or use the encryption method which you use (md5,sha1,any other for password)
Then you check out if it's returning a row. IF it's return 1 row,then everything is correct.

Then you put all this data to session. I don't know how much you need,but you can put the whole sql result to data. IT doesn't matter here as you said it's a dev class work.

So basically at every of your php you have to start with

```
session_start();
```

Then when you verified the user you put the sql result into SESSION like this:

```
$_SESSION['userdata'] = $sql_row_array;
```

With this data you can read the current loggedin user's informations. So it's like:
Get username: `$_SESSION['userdata']['username']`

So you can use this to identify whom bought / ordered the products and insert it into the database.

Comment: `md5,sha1` are methods that are no longer recommended to use. *Plus*, you don't encrypt password, you "**hash**" them. ;-)